# How to execute mongodb commands from pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I'm loading a collection from files in a python 2.7 script and I would like to execute somme commands from the script instead of doing them directly in the server CLI.

My code is like this:

```
import pymongo
...
def function(database)
  client = MongoClient()
  db=client[database]

  ... (populating the collection with documents, that works well) ...

  db.getSiblingDB('admin').runCommand({setParameter:1, failIndexKeyTooLoong: false})
  db.Collection.createIndex({"key":1})
  ...
```

I can't make those two last command work...
Is it even possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method for creating index is 'create_index', http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#indexing

also command is limited, but this is how you can run: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=command#pymongo.database.Database.command